# Can't find SUSEfirewall2 under /etc/sysconfig

Tags: linux, firewall, opensuse

so I'm trying to install LAMP on my Dell Laptop i have Open-SUSE Tumbleweed and
i have to edit a file called SUSEfirewall2 which the Open-SUSE-wiki says its in '/etc/sysconfig' but i can't find it ,i saw on a website (tho I'm not sure) that Open-SUSE started using firewalld instead of SUSEfirewall2 but if that's the case why didn't the Open-SUSE Wiki update there guide. All that being said I'm not sure so if I'm incorrect please tell me where to find the SUSEfirewall2 file so i can edit it.

P.S: Content of '/etc/sysconfig' :: 
apache2, backup, console, dmraid, irqbalance, language, mcelog, network, postfix, samba, services, sound, SuSEfirewall2.d, autofs, bootloader, cron, firewalld, issue-generator, lifecycle-report, mdadm, nfs, proxy, scripts, smartmontools, ssh, windowmanager, avahi, clock, displaymanager,  fonts-config, keyboard,         mail, mouse, pcscd, rpcbind, security, snapper, storage,  yast2.

Here's the guide i was following : https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:LAMP_setup

Comment: " why didn't the Open-SUSE Wiki update there guide" How would we know?

Comment: Fine. Then where can i find SUSEfirewall2 file it's not in the sysconfig directory as the guide says. i only installed tumbleweed like 1 week ago and I'm sure i didn't access that folder or delete any file before.

Comment: try this.....https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Support